# scss mixins not working error identifier expectedscss

Tags: sass

```
    @mixin search-box{
        padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
        border: 2px solid lightseagreen;
        width:100%;
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color:$color;
        font-family: $myFont;
        font-size: 23px;
    }

    .search-container{
        background:lightcyan;
        margin: 5px auto;
        width:30%;
        @include: search-box;
    }
```

Here I am using mixins in scss.
But it is giving me error identifier expectedscss(css-identifierexpected)

Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

`@include` is used like

```
@include <name>
```

So your styles would look like

```
@mixin search-box {
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  border: 2px solid lightseagreen;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: $color;
  font-family: $myFont;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.search-container {
  background: lightcyan;
  margin: 5px auto;
  width: 30%;
  @include search-box;
}
```